# Force fuction args type with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I want to force that arg to function will be str , so I used `:str` into function args

```
def func (a:str):
    print(a)
func(int(2))
```

This code is work and didn't fail , why?

Comment: Because [*"no type checking happens at runtime"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) - that is just metadata for developer tooling like MyPy, Python is still a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func (a:str):
    print(a)
func(int(2))
```

What you have used is *Type Hint* as described [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). Shortly speaking it is only guideline and do not have any enforcing effect. You might use `isinstance` function for checking if argument conforms to your requirement and `raise` `TypeError` otherwise following way:

```
def func(a):
    if not isinstance(a, str):
        raise TypeError
    print(a)
```

You can also (alongside the runtime check or instead of it) use a *static type checker* which will attempt to leverage those annotations (and possibly what it can infer from the un-annotated code) and check that they all match. By default Python (wilfully and knowingly) includes syntax to add type hints, but will not perform any type checking: that's not considered part of the python language itself (although there are parts of python which use the type *annotations*, like dataclasses).

The premier type-checker is [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) and developed under the umbrella of the Python project, but there are various alternatives (I've not necessarily tested so YMMV) e.g. Facebook's [pyre](https://pyre-check.org/), google's [pytype](https://google.github.io/pytype/) or microsoft's [pyright](https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright), as well as integrated tools such as the built-in type-checking of IDEs like jetbrains'.